# TSQL query to find latest (current) record from period column when there are past present and future records

Tags: sql, t-sql

edited as requested:
My apologies. I've been dealing with this a bit and it's well and truly in my head, but not for the reader.

We have multiple records in table A which have multiple entries in the Period column. Say it's like a football schedule. Teams will have multiple dates/times in the Period column.

When we run query:
**We want records selected for the most recent games only.**
**We don't want the earlier games.**
**We don't want the games "scheduled" and not yet played.**
**"Last game played" i.e. Period for teams are often on different days.**
Table like:
Team    Period
Reds    2021020508:00
Reds    2021011107:00
City    2021030507:00
Reds    2021032607:00
City    2021041607:00
Reds    2021050707:00

When I run query, I want to see the records for last game played regardless of date. So if I run the query on 27 Mar 2021, I want:

City    2021030507:00
Reds    2021032607:00

**Keep in mind I used the above as an easily understandable example. In my case I have 1000s of "Teams" each of which may have 100+ different date entries in the Period column and I would like the solution to be applicable regardless of number of records, dates, or when the query is run.**
What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what "current records no matter the date" means.

Comment: @Gordon, I mean that when a record exists that has Period of 2021032607:00 and I run my Select on 1 April at 1500 that I get that record as well as records with Period Date/Time up to 1 April at 1500, but if a record exist (and they do) which has the most recent Period of 2021021406:00 that these types of records will also be selected.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements even still, perhaps you can illustrate with some example expected results. Your `where` criteria is simply `Convert(varchar(9),GetDate(),112) + '%'`

Comment: My apologies. I've dealing with this a bit and it's well and truly in my head, but not for the reader.

Comment: Take a deep breath. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and consumable data keeps us from having to guess what "Reds 2021011107:00" means. Is that a `DateTime` value or some sort of encoded string? What have you tried? What issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

So this gives you your desired output using the sample data, does it fulfil your requirement?

```
create table x (Team varchar(10), period varchar(20))
insert into x values
('Reds','2021020508:00'),
('Reds','2021011107:00'),
('City','2021030507:00'),
('Reds','2021032607:00'),
('City','2021041607:00'),
('Reds','2021050707:00')


select Team, Max(period) LastPeriod
from x
where period <=Format(GetDate(), 'yyyyMMddhh:mm')
group by Team
```

Comment: Thanks Stu! This does indeed provide the requested data.

Comment: That's great. If it helps you out feel free to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The string-formatted date you have order by text, so I think this would work

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM tableA
WHERE period = FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddhh:mm' )
ORDER BY period
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
where period = (select max(t2.period) from t t2)
```

This returns all rows with the last period in the table.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want records for periods of 2021060407:00
2021051407:00
2021042307:00